# Macro or method to pivot data in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, unpivot

I am looking for a way to dynamically pivot data in an Excel sheet to put the data in a universal format no matter how wide the data set is.

For example: I want to be able to take a spreadsheet that could have 5 columns, 30 columns, or x number of columns to make it pivot to a universal format that is only three columns wide.

Here is a sample of how the original data could look:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do it, either by macro or using any other Excel functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumes labels/data is in Sheet1 starting A1.

1. Insert a new ColumnA.
2. For Excel 2003: Activate any cell in your summary table and choose Data - PivotTable and PivotChart Report:

   [image: SO20541905 first example]
3. For later versions access the Wizard with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, P:
4. Select *Multiple consolidation ranges* and *PivotTable* and click <kbd>Next ></kbd>.

   [image: SO20541905 second example]
5. In “Step 2a of 3”, choose *I will create the page fields* and click <kbd>Next ></kbd>.

   [image: SO20541905 third example]
6. In “Step 2b of 3” (not shown in the modal!) specify your summary table range in the **Range:** field (A2:E6 for the sample data) and click <kbd>Add</kbd>, then <kbd>Next ></kbd>.

[image: SO32982294 fourth example]

7. In “Step 3 of 3”, select a location for the PivotTable (the existing sheet should serve, as the PT is only required temporarily):

[image: SO32982294 fifth example]

8. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd> to create the PivotTable:

[image: SO32982294 sixth example]

9. Drill down (ie double-click) on the intersect of the Grand Totals (here Cell L4 or `16`):

[image: SO32982294 seventh example]

10. The PT may now be deleted.
11. In A2 of Table:

    `="Summary"&RIGHT(B2)`
12. Convert the resulting Table into a conventional array of cells by selecting **Table** in the Quick Menu (right-click in the Table) and **Convert to Range**.
13. In a spare column starting in Row2 series fill integers down, from `1` to however many rows of data you started with (`4`, in the example). Then series fill that series to suit.
14. Sort sheet by that (spare) column, Smallest to Largest, with *My data has headers* checked.
15. Delete Row1 and spare column and hopefully you will end up with:

    [image: SO32982294 eighth example]

Comment: This does it! Thank you for the very detailed response!

Comment: @pnuts if _this_ is more or less a copy of _that_ then shouldn't this be closed as a duplicate?